# Navigation Controller to View Controller Programmatically Not Working IOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Hi in my application i have navigation controller with registration and I'm doing the validation for my registration form if user enter a invalid data in the registration form it should not move to the next view controller and if user give the right data it should move to the next view controller but its not working.

```
     - (IBAction)reg:(id)sender {
   if ([self validateEmail:[email text]]== 1 && [self phonevalidate:[phone text]]== 1 && [name.text length] <= 25 && [city.text length] <= 25 ) {
       pollpoliticalViewController *pollVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PollPoliticalVCID"];
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:pollVC animated:YES];
       UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Thanks For The Registration" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
       [alert show];
       [alert release];


    }else{
       UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"you entered worng correct" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [alert1 show];
       [alert1 release];
    }
  }
```

I used this above code for the navigating to view controller form the navigation controller programmatically but its giving error like.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboard'

But my storyboard name is main.storyboard i don't know why its giving error like this i have tried to by chaining the storyboard name but what ever i change the its giving the same error for all please tell me how to resolve this one.

Thanks.

Comment: If the controller you're calling this code from is in the same storyboard as pollpoliticalViewController, then it's easier to just use self.storyboard. There's no need to use storyboardWithName:bundle:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The storyboard name does not contain the extension, try using `Main` instead of `Main.storyboard`

```
pollpoliticalViewController *pollVC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PollPoliticalVCID"];
```

From the official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboard/storyboardWithName%3abundle%3a):

Creates and returns a storyboard object for the specified storyboard resource file.

```
+(UIStoryboard *)storyboardWithName:(NSString *)name bundle:(NSBundle *)storyboardBundleOrNil
```

Parameters name **The name of the storyboard resource file without the filename extension**. This method raises an exception if this parameter is nil. [...]